# integrate Outlook or any webmail interface to my application

Tags: web-applications, outlook, email-client, webmail

I have developed a web application for management (ERP) and i want to integrate a mail interface to send and receive emails and files from/to customers via the application

How can I integrate Outlook or any webmail interface to my application?